# How to extract text from all the children of HTML tag through Selenium Webdriver in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have this HTML

```html
<tr height="22px">
    <td colspan="1" class="det" width="40%">Net Sales</td>

    <td align="right" class="det">2,548.00</td>
    <td align="right" class="det">1,946.36</td>
    <td align="right" class="det">1,139.14</td>
    <td align="right" class="det">2,345.60</td>
    <td align="right" class="det">1,323.84</td>
</tr>
```

I find the element using text:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("url")

quarterly_results_data = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*   [contains(text(),'Net Sales)]")

print(quarterly_results_data.text)
```

I get:

```
Net Sales
```

However I want all the text between parent `<tr>`:

```
Net Sales
2,548
1,946
...
```

Using :

```
print(quarterly_results_data.parent.text)
```

does not give any results.

I know it can be done by beautifulsoup, but I will have to use html parser every time i click on a new link.
Please help with the right syntax.

Comment: Please take a minute to fix the indent and spacing in the HTML so that it's easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get text of parent element as below:

```
quarterly_results_data = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Net Sales')]/parent::*")
print(quarterly_results_data.text)
```

or

```
quarterly_results_data = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[td[text()='Net Sales']]")
print(quarterly_results_data.text)
```

If you need to print out each `td` value separately:

```
for child in quarterly_results_data.find_elements_by_xpath('./td'):
    print(child.text)
```

Comment: The question is about how to get all child nodes text. Why are you writing about parent nodes?